# How can I calculate the same SSH fingerprint as Putty displays?

Tags: ssh

When first connecting to a new SSH host in Putty it displays a message asking me to verify the RSA fingerprint:

[image: Putty First Connection]

When viewing this same information on the network (e.g. through Wireshark), the same value is not shown, instead is shown as:

[image]

How can I calculate the fingerprint from the information shown in the Packet Capture?

Answer (score 0):

The value shown in wireshark is the full public key from the server.  The fingerprint (MD5 Hash value) of this value is shown to the user in putty as it's much easier (shorter) to read that expecting the user to match up the entire key.

To calculate the public key fingerprint it is necessary to first convert the hex stream given by Wireshark to the the byte stream equivilent then to calculate the MD5 hash from this and output in hexadecimal format.

A crude implementation of this in python is below which will take the wireshark value (HEX DH host Key copied as a HEX Stream) on STDIN and output the fingerprint on STDOUT:

```
import md5
import sys

# Accepts a wireshark encoded string on STDIN an outputs MD5 fingerprint to STDOUT

# The value copied from the 'HEX DH host Key' as a HEX Stream
wireshark_key = sys.stdin.readline()

# Change the HEX value into the raw byte stream, which will include non-printable characters
hex_string = wireshark_key.strip().decode("hex")

# Calculate the MD5 Hash of the byte stream and output in Hexidecimal     format
md5_fingerprint = md5.new(hex_string).hexdigest()

# Tidy up the output so it matches what Putty displays
putty_fingerprint = ":".join([md5_fingerprint[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(md5_fingerprint), 2)])

print(putty_fingerprint)
```

To run this, save the wireshark value (public key) to a file and then execute:

```
cat <key.txt> | python scriptname.py
```

The output should then match what is displayed by Putty on first connect as well as in the Event Log.

The following web pages were very useful in figured this all out:

http://passionateaboutis.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/ssh-fingerprint-from-pcap.html

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Public_Key_Authentication

Whilst this script may be useful for one off cases, if you need to obtain fingerprints for a large number of hosts, nmap and one of it's NSE scripts may be more efficient:

https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssh-hostkey.html

Saving the output from NMAP to XML will automatically store the calculated fingerprint for all hsots.